# How to optionally pass in a Binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that internally manages a @State variable that keeps track of the current index. So something like:

```swift
struct ReusableView: View {

    @State var index: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Text("The index is \(self.index)"
        // A button that changes the index
    }

}
```

This view is going to be reused throughout the app. Sometimes the parent view will need access to the index, so I refactored it like this:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var index: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
      ReusableView($index)
    }

}

struct ReusableView: View {

    @Binding var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("The index is \(self.index)"
        // A button that changes the index
    }

}
```

#### The problem

I don't want to enforce the parent view to **always** keep the state of the index. In other words, I want to optionally allow the parent view to be in charge of the state variable, but default to the Reusable View to maintain the state in case the parent view doesn't care about the index.

#### Attempt

I tried somehow to initialize the binding on the reusable view in case the parent view doesn't provide a binding:

```swift
struct ReusableView: View {

    @Binding var index: Int

    init(_ index: Binding<Int>? = nil) {
        if index != nil {
            self._index = index
        } else {
            // TODO: Parent didn't provide a binding, init myself.
            // ?
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("The index is \(self.index)"
        // A button that changes the index
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main problem with what you want to achieve is that when the index is handled by the parent your View needs a @Binding to it, but when it handles the index itself it needs @State. There are two possible solutions.

**If the view can ignore the index property when it doesn't have one:**

```
struct ReusableView: View {

    @Binding var index: Int?

    init(_ index: Binding<Int?>) {
        self._index = index
    }

    init() {
       self._index = .constant(nil)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            index.map { Text("The index is \($0)") }
        }
    }   
}
```

The advantage is that it is very straightforward - just two initializers, but you cannot change the value of the index when it is handled by ResusableView itself (its a constant).

**If the view cannot ignore the index property when it doesn't have one:**

```
struct ReusableView: View {

    private var content: AnyView

    init(_ index: Binding<Int>? = nil) {
        if let index = index {
            self.content = AnyView(DependentView(index: index))
        } else {
            self.content = AnyView(IndependentView())
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        content
    }

    private struct DependentView: View {

        @Binding var index: Int

        var body: some View {
            Text("The index is \(index)")
        }
    }

    private struct IndependentView: View {

        @State private var index: Int = 0

        var body: some View {
            Text("The index is \(index)")
        }
    }

}
```

The clear advantage is that you have a view that can either be bound to a value or manage it as its own State. As you can see ReusableView is just a wrapper around two different views one managing its own @State and one being bound to @State of its parent view.

Comment: I like it, from all the posts it seems that there is no canonical solution, but this is the most elegant I've seen.

Comment: You can make the .constant(nil) a default value to simplify things:

`init(_ index: Binding<Int?> = .constant(nil) )  {...} `

which removes the need for the second `init()` method

Comment: Note that the `IndependentView` `body` could be just an instance of `DependentView` as well, reducing duplicate code: `var body: some View { DependentView(index: $index) }`

Answer (score 1):

If it is not the goal to use dependency injection for binding, there is only one thing to bound to internally - internal `@State`. So here is alternate approach to use internal binding to internal state, you can try.

```
struct ReusableView: View {

    @Binding private var externalIndex: Int
    @State private var internalIndex: Int = 0
    private var hasExternal = false

    init(_ index: Binding<Int>? = nil) {
        if index != nil {
            self._externalIndex = index!
            self.hasExternal = true
        } else {
            self._externalIndex = Binding<Int>(get: {0}, set: {_ in}) // initialization stub
        }
    }

    private var index: Binding<Int> {
        hasExternal ? $externalIndex : $internalIndex
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The index is \(self.index.wrappedValue)")
            // A button that changes the index
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest to change in `init`, I think you are on the right direction.

In the UI world, when you try to `init` something, people prefer to add Views. So all you need one thing is to add a middle view between Parent and original reusable View. You don't need even change code of your views

```
           struct ParentView: View {
                @State var index: Int?
                var body: some View {
                    ReusableView(index: $index)
                }
            }

            struct ReusableView_Original: View {
                @Binding var index: Int
                var body: some View {
                    VStack{
                    Text("The index is \(self.index)")
                        Button.init("click", action:{
                            self.index += 1
                        })}
                }
            }
```

// Middle view is the following.

```
            struct ReusableView: View{
                @Binding var index: Int?
                var body: some View {
                    ReusableView_Original(index: Binding<Int>(get: {
                        return self.index == nil ? 0 : self.index!
                    }, set: { (int) in
                        self.index = int
                    }))
                }
            }
```

You can extend and test the result like this:

```
   struct ParentView: View {
                @State var index: Int? = 2
                var body: some View {
                    VStack{
                    ReusableView(index: $index)
                    ReusableView(index: $index, useDefault:  true)
                    }
                }
            }


            struct ReusableView: View{
                @Binding var index: Int?
                @State var useDefault = false
                @State var defaultValue = 0

                var body: some View {
                    ReusableView_Original(index: Binding<Int>(get: {
                        return self.useDefault ? self.defaultValue : self.index!
                    }, set: { (int) in
                        self.useDefault = false
                        self.index = int
                    }))
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here (to my opinion) is **custom Bindings** with a a **wrapper View**.

That will give you two choices:

1. Bind your (child) View with the parent View so that both parent and child can change the value
2. Don't bind child View with parent so that ONLY the child will save the value internally.

It's actually pretty straitforward.

This is your example, changed to work. 
Keep in mind that the actual change is the wrapper View and that you have to call the wrapper View from parent (instead of child).

**The parent View** (same as yours except child view)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view state: \(index ?? 0)")
            WrapperOfReusableView(index: self.$index)
            // if you add  .constant(nil) it will use the internal storage
        }
    }
}
```

**The wrapper View**

```
struct WrapperOfReusableView: View {
    // The external index
    @Binding var index: Int?
    // The internal index
    @State private var localIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        // Custom binding
        let localIndexBinding = Binding(
            get:{
                // if the parent sends nil, use the internal property
                self.index ?? self.localIndex
            },
            set: {
                // Set both internal and external
                self.localIndex = $0
                self.index = $0
            }
        )
        // return the actual View
        return ReusableView(index: localIndexBinding)
    }
}
```

**The actual View** (same as yours)

```
struct ReusableView: View {
    @Binding var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The Reusable index is \(index)")

            Button("Change Index") {
                self.index = self.index + 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to have a `@State` for the reusable view and sync it with the parent if needed. Because *There should be only one state manager for each view*. But it can be synced with an external manager.

So You may make it `optional` and add another internal `@State` for local changes:

```
struct ReusableView: View {

    @Binding var parentIndex: Int?
    @State private var defaultIndex = 0 { didSet { guard parentIndex != nil else { return }; parentIndex! += 1 } }
    var index: Int { parentIndex ?? defaultIndex }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The index is \(self.index)")
            Button("Reuseable") { self.defaultIndex += 1 }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can easily pass `.constant(nil)` when you don't want it to be handled by parent like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var index: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent: \(index!)")
            ReusableView(parentIndex: $index)
            Button("Parent") { self.index! += 1 }
            Divider()
            ReusableView(parentIndex: .constant(nil))
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that I added some buttons and actions and helpers to make it demonstrable, but you can of course change them all as you like</sub>

Answer (score -1):

In my experience it would be cleaner and more convenient to wrap your `index` in an `ObservableObject`.

```
class IndexStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published index = 0
}
```

Then in your `ReusableView`

```
struct ReusableView: View {

    var indexStore = IndexStore()

    var body: some View {
        Text("The index is \(self.indexStore.index)"
        // A button that changes the index
    }

}
```

Then you can instantiate it as `ReusableView()` for "internal" index, `ReusableView(indexStore: parentIndexStore)` for parent's index, and even share indexes among different `ReusableView`'s.

Comment: Thanks, although this works I'm looking for a binding solution

Comment: I learned the hard way that you shouldn't force SwiftUI and Combine for things it wasn't designed for.